# detect the row of which cell has been pressed

Tags: ios, swift

I have built a to do list app in swift. I want it so that If I click on the table view cell, it would go to another view controller and display that to do list item.

Also, I have an app which is similar, except it stores your favorite url's. Again I want the user to be able to click the cell, and show the url. I also have a web view which I want to show the url the user has pressed on.

Comment: Do some online tutorials. This one includes the basics of table views. https://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-part-1

Comment: You should follow some tutorials, this is very common and is clearly documented everywhere. Please read the Delegate, DataSource protocols documentation.

Answer (score 6):

This is documented quite clearly in docs for `UITableView`.

When you set up a table view you designate some object (usually the view controller) as it's delegate. That delegate needs to conform to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol.

There is a method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in that protocol. If you implement that method, the table view will call it when the user clicks a cell.